# What is the best way to fix the 'AddThis' social links in Big Commerce

Tags: blogs, bigcommerce

In Big Commerce (LifeStyle theme), what is the best way to fix the 'AddThis' social links not working on blog posts? Apparently this is reliant on JavaScript from the 'AddThis' server themselves which has apparently shut down as per [this post](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/question/0D54v00009BNPBUCA5/social-media-share-icons-arent-working?language=en_US). It could be manually done in the **components/common/share.html** file but I'm looking for the least messy solution.

Comment: StackOverflow is best used for [Minimal, Reproducible Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What have you tried? What hasn't worked?

Comment: @sheng Yeh I get that. As I say it can be done manually in the file mentioned but I'm just seeing if anyone has experience of a solution that is more admin based and less intrusive. Messing in files can cause a few more headaches when updating themes, etc. Thanks